# fancyBox Image Number

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I wonder whether someone may be able to help.

I've created an image gallery using fancyBox, as shown in the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
<head>  
  <title>Gallery</title>  
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/lib/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.0.6"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.2"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.2"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.0"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.2" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.2" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.0.6" media="screen" />


  <script type="text/javascript">  

            $('.fancybox').fancybox({
                openEffect  :   'elastic',
                closeEffect :   'elastic',

                padding :   20,
                fitToView   :   true,

                prevEffect :    'none',
                nextEffect :    'none',

                closeBtn  : false,
                arrows : false,

                helpers : {
                    title : {
                        type : 'inside'
                    },
                    buttons : {}
                },

                afterLoad : function() {
                    this.title = 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length + (this.title ? ' - ' + this.title : '');
                }
            });


</script> 
  <style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 110px;
}
-->
  </style>  
</head>
<body style="font-family: Calibri; color:  #505050; margin-left: 240px; float:left;"/>
<div align="right" class="style1"> <a href = "javascript:document.gallery.submit()"/> Add Images <a/> &larr; View Uploaded Images </div> 
  <form id="gallery" name="gallery" class="page" action="index.php" method="post" style="margin-left: -120px; margin-right: 50px;"> 

    <p>
      <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $descriptions->documentElement->childNodes->length; $i++) :  
                          $xmlFile = $descriptions->documentElement->childNodes->item($i);  
                          $name = htmlentities($xmlFile->getAttribute('originalname'), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');  
                          $description = htmlentities($xmlFile->getAttribute('description'), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');  
                          $source = $galleryPath . rawurlencode($xmlFile->getAttribute('source'));  
                          $thumbnail = $thumbnailsPath . rawurlencode($xmlFile->getAttribute('thumbnail'));  
                  ?>
      <a class="fancybox" rel="allimages" title="<?php echo $name; ?>" href="<?php echo $source; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>"alt="<?php echo $description; ?>" /></a>
      <?php endfor; ?>  
    </p>
</form>  
</body>
</html>
```

Everything works well except for the page numbering i.e. the 'Image Number of...' text only appears on the first image.

I've taken this code directly from the 'fancyapps' site, so I'm a little unsure where the error is as they both seem identical.

I just wondered whether someone could perhaps have a look at this please and let me know where I've gone wrong.

Many thanks and regards

Comment: A self contained jsFiddle example would be extremely helpful here.

Comment: Hi, yes I know and I'm really very sorry that I've not provided this. To be honest I'm not sure how to use jsFiddle, and I didn't want to make a mess of the post. I'll have a look now and see what I can put together. The problem I also have is that the script runs on PHP and I wasn't sure whether PHP could be used in jsFiddle. To help a little more I have amended my original post and added the full page script. Kind regards

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your fancybox custom script inside `$(document).ready(function(){ // fancybox script here});`?

Comment: Hi @JFK, many thanks for taking the time to reply. Unfortunately even after adding this I still have the same problem. Kind regards

Comment: Try the latest source code - https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/zipball/master

Comment: Hi @Janis, this is great it works a treat. Many thansk for taking the time to help. Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the new verison of 'fancyBox' this has now been resolved and the image number works fine.